# FileProvider.GetUriForFile() occur RuntimeException in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am going to take a photo from Camera in Xamarin Android.

Here's what I did in Xamarin.

1. Start Camera Activity

   ```
   private void CallTakePictureIntent ()
   {
       Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
       // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
       if (takePictureIntent.ResolveActivity (PackageManager) != null) {
           // Create the File where the photo should go
           Java.IO.File photoFile = null;
           try {
               photoFile = ImageHelper.CreateImageFile (this);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               System.Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString ());
           }
           // Continue only if the File was successfully created
           if (photoFile != null) {
               sURI photoURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile (this, UIHelper.FileProvider, photoFile);
               requestedAvatarUri = photoURI;
               takePictureIntent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, photoURI);
               StartActivityForResult (takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create temporary file.

   ```
   public static Java.IO.File CreateImageFile (Context context)
   {
       // Create an image file name
       string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
       string imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
       Java.IO.File storageDir = context.GetExternalFilesDir (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
       Java.IO.File image = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile (
               imageFileName,  /* p                refix */
               ".jpg",         /* suffix */
               storageDir      /* directory */
       );
       return image;
   }
   ```
3. Android.Manifest

   ```
       <provider
       android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="com.masterbee.xamapp-dev.fileprovider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
   </provider>
   ```
4. xml/file_paths.xml

   ```
   <external-path name="external_images" path="Pictures/" />
   ```

I think I've done correctly, all things work except runtime exception in FileProvider.GetUriForFile() line.

Here's call trace.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeJPh.png)

Comment: `// Create the File where the photo should go`. Do not create the file. You only need an uri. The camara app will create the file.

Comment: For the rest you should post the complete exception of course, There is more info!

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your reply. I attached call trace. I am using another way which Xamarin Guide recommend. it works.